# jersey client not throwing exceptions property

Tags: java, jersey-client

I'm using jersey client to post data to a webservice. I've noticed some weird behavior from Jersey client.

I'm using following code:

```
    WebResource resource=null;
    try {
        ClientResponse response =   resource.accept(mediaType).post(ClientResponse.class, requestEntity);

System.out.println("Successful response received, statusCode=" + jerseyClientResponse.getStatus());)

    } catch (UniformInterfaceException e) {
        ClientResponse r = e.getResponse();
        System.out.println("Exception from server, statusCode="+r.getStatus());
    }
```

If server returns 404 status,  I'm expecting jersey to throw UniformInterfaceException exception but when I execute the code, I get following message:

```
Successful response received, statusCode=404
```

Can anyone tell me why is UniformInterfaceException not getting thrown?

I'm using jersey client version 1.18.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to the docs (https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.8/jersey/index.html?com/sun/jersey/api/client/UniformInterfaceException.html) a UniformInterfaceException is thrown "if the status of the HTTP response is greater than or equal to 300 and c is not the type ClientResponse".  In your case "c" is of type ClientResponse so the exception is not thrown.

Comment: Thanks! I missed it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me why is UniformInterfaceException not getting
>   thrown?

It is defined in the [contract for this method](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/1.4/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html).

> UniformInterfaceException - if the status of the HTTP response is
>   greater than or equal to 300 and c is not the type ClientResponse.

Use a type other than client response to get the desired result.

```
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client
            .resource("http://google.com/fake/no_url");
    Object requestEntity = null;
    final String post = webResource.post(String.class, requestEntity);
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException: POST http://google.com/fake/no_url returned a response status of 411 Length Required
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:686)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

I missed **c is not the type ClientResponse** completely :(